# Make a slider controlling a generated character's code value

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, character-encoding

If I execute the following code:

```
char = 97;
Slider[Dynamic@ToExpression@FromCharacterCode@char, {0, 5}]
```

the slider will fail to change the value of `a`.

How do you make this work, when the expression has to be generated with `FromCharacterCode` or similar?

**Note:**

```
ToExpression@FromCharacterCode@97 == a
```

Comment: you have commented about `a` further below but you should fix up this question describing what `a` is and how it relates to `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest thing would be to put the string `"Dynamic@"` inside `ToExpression`:

```
Slider[ToExpression["Dynamic@" <> FromCharacterCode@char], {0, 5}]
```

This creates a slider which controls the value of the symbol `a`, which I think is what you are asking for.

Comment: Very slick. :-)

Answer (score 4):

How about using `With`?

```
char = 97;
With[{var = ToExpression@FromCharacterCode@char},
  Slider[Dynamic@var, {0, 5}]
]
```

or, if `a` already exists, following Simon Woods' suggestion:

```
char = 97;
With[{var = ToExpression[FromCharacterCode@char, InputForm, Unevaluated]},
  Slider[Dynamic@var, {0, 5}]
]
```

Comment: You might want to use `ToExpression[FromCharacterCode@char, InputForm, Unevaluated]` in case `a` already has a value.

Comment: @SimonWoods Good point!

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean something like this:

```
Clear[char];
{Slider[Dynamic[char], {67, 97, 1}], Dynamic[FromCharacterCode[char]]}
```

The syntax in your question was incorrect because the dynamic variable in the first argument of `Slider` can't be a protected function name.

**Edit**

You also had a `ToExpression` in your question. That can be added in this answer too, obviously by writing `ToExpression@FromCharacterCode`. Then you just have to make sure your character range doesn't include characters that yield an error when fed into `ToExpression`.

**Edit 2**
In response to the comment, I think what you should do is to write

```
a = Dynamic[ToExpression@FromCharacterCode[char]]
```

with the above slider (or some version of it).

Comment: No I want it to change a value generated by `FromCharacterCode` and in my example it should modify `a`.

Comment: But your example code does not contain any variable `a`! What is the variable `a`, and what is it supposed to be changed to?

Comment: `ToExpression@FromCharacterCode@97 == a`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another formulation:

```
Slider[Dynamic @@ ToHeldExpression @ FromCharacterCode @ char, {0, 5}]
```